# Selenium timing out on every request. How can I make this more reliable?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape prices where I have the URL and from there I determine the which xpath to use based on the retailer. This is a simplified version of what I'm doing inside a Django app. The only difference here is I'm looping over a list of URLs rather than the database.

I'd like to know why I keep getting 'timeout' for all the prices and what I could do to optomise this approach.

Should I make it so if I get TimeoutException that I rotate to a new proxy until it works?

I'm using element_to_be_clickable under the impression it will be best for sites that use React or jQuery,

I hope to be able to scrape dozens of prices from each retailer twice per week. Is there anything I should keep in mind to avoid getting blocked?

Also apparently Python doesn't have a switch-case feature so I have this if / elif thing going on.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import random
import time


DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'

XPATHS = {
    'wayfair': '//*[@id="bd"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span',
    'eq3': "//span[contains(@class,'MuiTypography-root') and contains(@class,'MuiTypography-h3')][1]",
    'elte': '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/span',
    'crate_&_barrel': '//*[@id="react_0HM7EN3OE6904"]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span',
    'bouclair': '//*[@id="ordering-panel"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/span/span[2]/span',
    'article': '//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span'
}

URLS = [
    'https://www.article.com/product/11836/sven-charme-chocolat-sofa',
    'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/zipcode-design-evan-726-wide-square-arm-convertible-sofa-zpcd1679.html',
    'https://www.bouclair.com/en/furniture/seating/dining-chairs/textured-faux-leather-and-metal-dining-chair-9393613M.html',
]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'dnt': '1'
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={headers}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)

for url in URLS:
    driver.get(url)

    def wait_for_element(xpath):
        return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, xpath)))

    if ('wayfair.ca' in url or 'wayfair.com' in url):
        print("Retailer: Wayfair")
        try:
            price = wait_for_element(XPATHS['wayfair']).text or None
        except TimeoutException:
            price = 'Timeout'
    elif ('eq3.com' in url):
        print("Retailer: EQ3")
        try:
            price = wait_for_element(XPATHS['eq3']).text or None
        except TimeoutException:
            price = 'Timeout'

    elif ('elte.com' in url):
        print("Retailer: ELTE")
        try:
            price = wait_for_element(XPATHS['elte']).text or None
        except TimeoutException:
            price = 'Timeout'

    elif ('crateandbarrel.com' in url):
        print("Retailer: Crate & Barrel")
        try:
            price = wait_for_element(XPATHS['crate_&_barrel']).text or None
        except TimeoutException:
            price = 'Timeout'

    elif ('bouclair.com' in url):
        print("Retailer: Bouclair")
        try:
            price = wait_for_element(XPATHS['bouclair']).text or None
        except TimeoutException:
            price = 'Timeout'

    elif ('article.com' in url):
        print("Retailer: Article")
        try:
            price = wait_for_element(XPATHS['article']).text or None
        except TimeoutException:
            price = 'Timeout'

    print('price', price)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5)) # Sleep for 3 - 5 seconds

driver.quit()
```

Comment: //*[@id="bd"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span','eq3'  - this is not reliable

Answer (score 0):

simply because you are passing a dict in `options.add_argument(f"user-agent={headers}")`
where value for user-agent should simply be

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'
```

for others if you are getting a timeout, it might be because of xpath error.